# How to force invoke the error handler from a unit test using the flask app test_client during a GET/POST request?

Tags: python, flask

I have unittests on my flask app that invoke the GET/POST endpoints using the flask app test_client.

Suppose I want to test the error response for an endpoint, then how can I force invoke the error handler?